# Ryu controller - [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Tags: mininet, ryu

[image: Broken pipe]

I'm using Ryu controller to controll virtualized switches in a topology made from mininet network emulator. I suddenly started to get more of **"[Errno 32] Broken pipe"** errors, when i haven't made any changes to controller.

Could you please tell me what's wrong and how to correct it?
Please contact me if you need more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these two:

1. Exit mininet usin `quit`, closing the terminal is not a clean. When you close mininet ALWAYS run `sudo mn -c`. This will clean the mininet and its the traces. Essentially it will be ready for next run. When you do this make sure there is no controller running.
2. Run your controller and mininet command using `sudo`.

In general restart the your vm/pc.

Let me know if that helped.

Comment: It helped. Thanks a lot :)